# jQuery plugin qtip2 - Close tool tip on mouse over of close button

Tags: jquery, qtip2

jQuery plugin qtip2, jQuery 1.7.2 - Planning to implement qtip2 in my project and I would like to close the tool tip when I  hover over the close button at the top right instead of clicking the button to close the tool tip. Please see my code,

**HTML**

```
  <a href="/wiki/Quantum_mechanics" title="Wikipedia: Quantum mechanics">quantum mechanics</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
        $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('a[title]').qtip({
            content: {
                title: {
                    text: 'About me',button: 'Close'
                }
            },
            show: {
                solo: true
            },
            hide: 'unfocus'
        });
    });
```

Please see the code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/evapix/1/)

**Update**

Based on Gustavo Simon's answer, the code to close the tool tip on mouse over,

```
     $("body").on("mouseenter", "a.qtip-close", function(){
        $(this).closest("div.qtip").hide('slow');
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution but works:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", "a.qtip-close", function(){
            $('a[title]').qtip('api').hide();
});
```

I hope it helps